# ASP.NET DirectoryServices.AccountManagement "Access is denied"

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, directoryservices

I'm trying to create an interface in ASP.NET that would allow the user to add or remove a member from an AD group. 
I'm using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement classes and I've managed to create the PrincipalContext and list users that are in a specified group, but when I go to add a user to that GroupPrincipal, I get an "Access is denied" error.

Is it the IIS server user that executes the codebehind at runtime, or does it pass the currently logged in Windows user credentials ?

Comment: Depends on how you've configured it.  Generally, it's the AppPool worker identity, but if you've configured the process for Impersonation then it will use the logged on users identity.

Comment: Thanks! I've verified the identity, and it was set to a user that did not have write access to AD. I've changed it to use the windows credentials and now it works (based on who is logged in).